# I can ping to the Win10 successfully from my Mac. I cannot access the jupyter with chrome/edge browser from my Mac. How do I do?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running jupyter-notebook 6.3.0 on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1165].

I've set the config file following the [doc](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html)

```
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
```

I can access the jupyter on my Win10 with chrome/edge browser with `http://192.168.1.108:8888`

I can ping to the Win10 (192.168.1.108) successfully from my Mac.

I cannot access the jupyter (http://192.168.1.108:8888) with chrome/edge browser from my Mac and get this error

```
xxx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503
```

How do I do?

Comment: It doesn't work maybe because jupyter is not listening for connection on you networks. It is only listening for local connection from same pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `jupyter notebook --ip <your_LAN_ip> --port 8888` Then visit `http://your_LAN_ip:8888` from another computer.

Or

In your case replace the line `c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'` with `c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'` to listen on all IPs
And add these two lines

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' # allow access from anywhere
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True # allow cross-site requests
```

It's recommended that you use a password when accessing your notebook server. To set up a password, just run `jupyter notebook password`. To make it even more secure, you can use SSL for your server by passing the arguments `--certfile` and `--keyfile` to `jupyter notebook`